# Eclipse Scala IDE "unable to locate its companion companion library"

Tags: eclipse, scala

I cannot make the Scala IDE Eclipse running on my mac. When I try to launch it via launchpad it says

> "Eclipse quit unexpectedly."

When I use the terminal, it says:

> "The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library."

I have another eclipse installed on my Mac and it works just fine.

I've did my research both here and on google, but did not find anything that applies to my problem. Can anybody help me, please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things you can do.  One solution can be found here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-ide-user/-otJ8zNoNhc

The other is to:

1. Right click on the Eclipse.app icon (It might look like just "Eclipse")
2. Select "Show Package Contents"
3. Enter the MacOS folder, and launch eclipse from there.

If there is an easier way to do this, I hope someone posts it.